# how to execute JMX monitoring without restarting tomcat

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, monitoring, jmx, jmc

i am wondering if there is a possibility to configure a JMX monitoring without restarting my TOMCAT server since it is still working

i want to add the below commands in a setenv.sh file

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8008
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

i want also to make a secure connection using SSL but i don't have any idea to create and import the certificates

Comment: Note that jconsole and jvisualvm (with the MBeans plugin) can attach to a running process on the same machine and access beans even if you did not open up a port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running on the Oracle JDK you can use jcmd to bring up the remote agent.

jcmd <pid> ManagementAgent.start jmxremote.port=8008 jmxremote.ssl=false jmxremote.authenticate=false

Where <pid> is the process identifier of the process for which you want to start the agent.

Comment: I should add that there is plenty of documentation on how to set up certificates etc available. Google it. :)